# c - fscanf segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

Really strange problem with fscanf. It seems as if it can't find the file. Heres the code:

```
char obs_file[255];
FILE *obs_fp;

strcpy(obs_file, "/aber/dap/cetaceans/data/observers_1.txt");

obs_fp = fopen(obs_file, "r");

date_time t;
fscanf(obs_fp, "%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", &t.day, &t.mth, &t.yr, &t.hrs, &t.mns, &t.scs); //This line runs fine
obs_head.obs->time = t;
printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", t.day, t.mth, t.yr, t.hrs, t.mns, t.scs);

while(feof(obs_fp) == 0) {

    char id[5];
    char a[7];
    char b[7];
    location loc;
    double lng = 0.0, lat = 0.0;
    fscanf(obs_fp, "%s %lf %lf", id, &lat, &lng);  //Seg fault here on first run of loop
    loc.lat = lat;
    loc.lng = lng;
    add_obs_node(make_obs_node(id, loc, t));
}
```

File to be read:

```
05 11 2014 14 53 00
AB01 52.408 -4.217
```

It seems like the file pointer has changed somewhere around the while statement, I would understand if I was reading over the end of file, but it fails while there are definitely lines left. Also, I know Im opening the file right, as the first fscanf runs fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is `id` declared? Is it allocated?

Comment: 1) Check result of `fscanf(obs_fp, "%d %d %d %d %d %d\n"...` 2) do not use `while(feof(obs_fp) ... fscanf(obs_fp, "%s %lf %lf"`, use `while (fscanf(obs_fp, "%4s %lf %lf", id, &lat, &lng) == 3) {` .

Comment: id is declared `char id[5]` on the line below `while`.

Comment: I know `feof` wouldn't work, I was going to fix that bit later, the problem occurs on the first line of input, so I am definitely not going over EOF regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong use of `feof()` and unlimited `fscanf("%s"...`

`feof()` reports if EOF occurred due to previous IO, not if it is about to occur.

Use instead

```
char id[5];
double lng = 0.0, lat = 0.0;
while(fscanf(obs_fp, "%4s%lf%lf", id, &lat, &lng) == 3) {
  loc.lat = lat;
  loc.lng = lng;
  add_obs_node(make_obs_node(id, loc, t));
}
```

I suspect original code failed on the 2nd iteration.  Assume the last data in the file was `"AB01 52.408 -4.217\n"`. `fscanf(obs_fp, "%s %lf %lf"` would scan up to the `"\n"` and put `"\n"` back into `stdin` as it is not part of a `double`.  EOF flag is not set.  The use of `feof()` signals no EOF.  So `fscanf(obs_fp, "%s %lf %lf"` happens again, but no data is save in `id`, as `"%s"` consume leading white-space but has not non-white-space to save.  Code does not check the `fscanf()` return value (bad), but assumes good data in `id`, which may be junk.  Then `add_obs_node()` is called with an invalid string `id`.

Other failure mechanisms could have occurred too - need to see more code.

Bottom line: Check `fscanf()` results. Limit string input.

---

Minor: Note that the spaces between `"%d %d"` are not needed, but OK  to have.  The final `"\n"` is also OK but not needed.  It is not simply consuming the following `'\n'`, but any and all following white-space.

```
if (6 != fscanf(obs_fp, "%d%d%d%d%d%d", 
    &t.day, &t.mth, &t.yr, &t.hrs, &t.mns, &t.scs)) {
  Handle_BadData();
}
```

Comment: The code fails on the first iteration, I stepped through and the first time it reaches the line `fscanf(obs_fp, "%s %lf %lf", id, &lat, &lng);` it seg faults. I have also tried your suggested code, and that gives the same error, failing on the `while(fscanf...` line

Comment: @user168057 Let's try some basics:  Is `obs_fp != NULL`?, does the first `fscanf()` return 6?  Is `#include <stdio.h>` used?  If the `t` structure all `int`s?

Comment: @user168057 Is this does not reveal the problem, suggest a more robust approach: separate IO from parsing.  `char buf[100]; while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, obs_fp)) { if (3 != sscanf(buf, "%4s%lf%lf", ...) break; ... }`.

Comment: Ok, I haven't directly checked the first two, but I have tried printing the data back out, and that is fine, so I clearly can read the file at least somewhat. I have that include, and yes it is all `int`s

Comment: your `fgets` and `sscanf` solution worked, I think my actual issue boiled down to overflow coming from the wrong use of `malloc` (I wasn't dereferencing the pointer inside `sizeof`) Thanks!